# Java: I made a program that accepts input for an integer array & displays values in a table. Trying to recreate this using a string array. Pls. help,

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-input

Java is my first programming language, and I'm still unfamiliar with how arrays work. However, I was able to make this program, which accepts user-input for an integer array; it then outputs indexes and values, to show how arrays store numbers. I would like to recreate this program using a string array, to make a table containing a list of friends.

The .length property also confuses me...

*Could someone explain the .length property and help me make the string array program work?*

Thank you very much.

## Here is the working code for the integer array table program

```
import java.util.*;

public class AttemptArrayTable 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Let me show you how arrays are stored ");
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want your array to       
store? ");
        int arrayInput [] = new int[scan.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Enter numbers ");
        for (int count = 0; count<arrayInput.length; count++)
            arrayInput[count] = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Index\t\tValue");
        for (int count2=0; count2<arrayInput.length; count2++)
            System.out.println(" [" + count2 + "]"+"\t\t  " + arrayInput[count2]);
    }

}
```

## Here is the code for the string array program I'm working on

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayTableofFriends 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many female friends do you have? ");
        String arrayOfFriendsFem [] = new String [scan.nextInt()];
                System.out.println("List the name of your female friends");
                for(int countF = 0; countF<arrayOfFriendsFem.length; countF++)
                        arrayOfFriendsFem[countF]= scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How many male friends do you have? ");
        String arrayOfFriendsMale [] = new String [scan.nextInt()];
                System.out.println("List the name of your male friends");
                for(int countM = 0; countM<=arrayOfFriendsFem.length; countM++)
                    arrayOfFriendsMale[countM]= scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How many alien friends do you have? ");
        String arrayOfFriendsAliens [] = new String [scan.nextInt()];
                System.out.println("List the name of your alien friends");
                    for(int countA = 0; countA<=arrayOfFriendsFem.length; countA++)
                        arrayOfFriendsAliens[countA]= scan.nextLine();
        {


            System.out.println("Female\t\t\t" + "Male\t\t\t" + "Aliens");
            for(int countF2 = 0; countF2<arrayOfFriendsFem.length; countF2++)
                    System.out.println(arrayOfFriendsFem[countF2]);

            for(int countM2 = 0; countM2<=arrayOfFriendsMale.length; countM2++)
                System.out.println("\t\t\t" + arrayOfFriendsMale[countM2]);

            for(int countA2 = 0; countA2<=arrayOfFriendsAliens.length; countA2++)
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t" +arrayOfFriendsAliens[countA2]);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Array incidences start from 0, so when you iterate over an array of length = 3 you need incidences : 0,1,2 .  Change `countA<=arrayOfFriendsFem.length`  to `countA<arrayOfFriendsFem.length` . This error repeats in several places in the code.  Also you have a copy-paste error here : `int countA = 0; countA<=arrayOfFriendsFem.length; countA++`

Answer (score 1):

`.length` property stores number of elements in the array. But elements are starting from `0`. So, when `.length = 1`, then there is only one element in the array, with index `0`.

It seems in your String arrays program in the for loop the `<=` should be changed to `<`

Like this:

```
 for (int countA = 0; countA < arrayOfFriendsFem.length; countA++)
```